# How to remove all duplicates and similiar queries from Django admin

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a lot different models in my project and in every of them there's a duplicated SQL queries

I want to know how to remove them but the main problem is that in one model when I'm trying to take a look on single object of this model I have like 5k SQL queries.

I also tried to for loop all of information from this model in my template and still got ~5k queries how does it work?

models.py

```
class PresenceSectionList(models.Model):
    presence_detail = models.ForeignKey(PresenceDetailInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    presence_sections = models.ForeignKey(CleanSections, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Раздел с информацией'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Разделы с информацией'
        ordering = ['presence_detail', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.presence_detail}'

class CleanSections(models.Model):
    GUID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name='Краткое наименование')
    details = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Описание', blank=True)

class ObjectList(models.Model):
    GUID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Наименование')
    customer_guid = models.ForeignKey(CounterParty, related_name='customer_guid', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      verbose_name='Наименование заказчика', default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    contractor_guid = models.ManyToManyField(CounterParty, related_name='contractor_guid',
                                             verbose_name='Наименование подрядчика', default=None, blank=True)

    sections = models.ManyToManyField('SectionList', default=None, related_name='section', verbose_name='Разделы',
                                      blank=True)

class CounterParty(models.Model):
    GUID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Наименование')
    customer = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Заказчик')
    contractor = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Подрядчик')
    counter_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='counter_user',
                                          verbose_name='Пользователи контрагента')
```

admin.py

```
class PresenceSectionListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('presence_detail', 'presence_sections')
    ordering = ['presence_detail__presence_info', 'presence_detail__work_date']

admin.site.register(PresenceSectionList, PresenceSectionListAdmin)
```

[Number of SQL queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlflp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Django Admin loads a list of `PresenceSectionList` objects, then it accesses two attributes: `presence_detail` and `presence_sections` on each object. Since these fields are relations, then Django needs to fetch one `PresenceDetailInfo` and one `CleanSections` object **per each `PresenceSectionList`**.

This is very inefficient way. It would be much better to use [.select_related() QuerySet's method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). This will fetch the main model and related models in one query.

In django admin you need to override `get_queryset()` method:

In your `PresenceSectionListAdmin` class, add:

```py
def get_queryset(request):
    base_qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    return base_qs.select_related("presence_detail", "presence_sections")
```

This should reduce number of queries.

PS. I can also see many duplicated queries `FROM common_counterpart` in your screenshot, which I can't see in your example code. You can try **select_related** or [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) (in case of m2m relations.)

Comment: I added more models in my question can you help? Idk how to actually  use select related if i dont have ForeignKey to that model in my main PresenceSectionList

Comment: If your model has `relation1` foreign key to another model, and that another model has `relation2` key to a third model, then you can use `select_related` like so: `select_related("relation1__relation2")`. You should find the exact explanation in the docs I've linked in the answer.